# Use Lua to count occurrences in a file and rewrite the file

Tags: file, count, lua, url-rewriting

I have a Lua script that adds someone's name to a list in a file everytime something occurs.

What I want is this file to be rewritten with the occurrences, or "live" updating of the file.

This is the file, for example.

```
Albert
Albert
Albert
Bert
Bert
Albert
Cedric
Cedric
```

This is generated by this piece of code

```
function add_stats(name)
    local f = io.open(stats_file, "a")
    local text = tostring(f:read("*all"))
    f:write("\n", name)
    f:close()
end
```

So far I have been able to count the occurrences using this

```
function get_stats(name)
    local f2 = assert(io.open(stats_file, "r"))
    local text2 = tostring(f2:read("*all"))
    local _, count = string.gsub(text2, name, "")
    f2:close()
    return name .. " = " .. count
end
```

But this results in the stats file being filled with endless lines of code.

Ideally I want the file to look like this

```
Albert 6
Bert 5
Cedric 9
```

And when Albert triggers the script, it should update to 10.

Comment: Try http://lua-users.org/wiki/TableSerialization

Comment: It's not clear what you need. Your `add_stats` function opens `stats_file` for append, and then tries to read from it. The variable `text` will be set to `nil`, but that doesn't really matter as you're not using the value anyway.  Then you append a newline and the value of `name`. Your `get_stats just opens and reads the whole of the file and then counts the occurrences of the value of `name`. Neither of these functions have anything to do with the file format that you say you want. Do you really need to write this information to a file? Can't you keep it all in a table?

Comment: Whoops, the add_stats shouldn't read the file, my bad.
I'm not sure if this format is correct. This script "listens" to names of people, and all it has to do is keep track of how often the script is triggered, by which name. Tables are very abstract and confusing to me, that's why I went the way which I did.